# Memory not freed when running TensorFlow Inception v3?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I am trying to classify a set of photos (<10000) using Tensorflow Inception v3.

I'm using the [TensorFlow Docker installation CPU Binary image plus source code](http://gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel) on a Macbook Air with 4gb DDR3.

I've written a python script to spawn a subprocess to classify each image:

```
"""
classifier_spawner.py

Runs custom_classify_image.py in subprocess
"""
if __name__ == "__main__":
  import sqlite3
  import subprocess as sub
  from ast import literal_eval

  conn = sqlite3.connect("database_name.db")
  c = conn.cursor()
  c.execute("SELECT * FROM images")
  images = c.fetchall()
  for image in images:
      p = sub.Popen(["python", "custom_classify_image.py", "--image_file=image_dir/" + str(image[0]) + ".jpg"], stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE)
      output, errors = p.communicate()
      categories = literal_eval(output)
      for cat in categories:
          c.execute("""INSERT OR IGNORE INTO classification (image_id, class_id, probability) VALUES(?,?,?)""", (str(image[0]), str(cat[0]), float(cat[1])))
          conn.commit()
  print("Classification complete, exiting.")
  conn.close()
```

I have amended run_inference_on_image(image) in [classify_image.py as provided with TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/imagenet/classify_image.py) to print a python list of tuples of the top 5 classifications, as shown.

```
"""My custom run_inference_on_image(image) """

def run_inference_on_image(image):
  """Runs inference on an image.

  Args:
    image: Image file name.

  Returns:
Nothing
  """
  if not tf.gfile.Exists(image):
    tf.logging.fatal('File does not exist %s', image)
  image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image, 'rb').read()

  # Creates graph from saved GraphDef.
  """Creates a graph from saved GraphDef file and returns a saver."""
  # Creates graph from saved graph_def.pb.
  with tf.gfile.FastGFile(os.path.join(
      FLAGS.model_dir, 'classify_image_graph_def.pb'), 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
      with tf.Session() as sess:
        # Some useful tensors:
        # 'softmax:0': A tensor containing the normalized prediction across
        #   1000 labels.
        # 'pool_3:0': A tensor containing the next-to-last layer containing 2048
        #   float description of the image.
        # 'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': A tensor containing a string providing JPEG
        #   encoding of the image.
        # Runs the softmax tensor by feeding the image_data as input to the graph.
        softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('softmax:0')
        predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor,
                           {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
        predictions = np.squeeze(predictions)

        # Creates node ID --> English string lookup.
        node_lookup = NodeLookup()

        top_k = predictions.argsort()[-FLAGS.num_top_predictions:][::-1]
        top_k_tup_list = []
        for node_id in top_k:
          human_string = node_lookup.id_to_string(node_id)
          score = predictions[node_id]
          top_k_tup_list.append((human_string, score))
        sess.close()
        print(top_k_tup_list)
```

My issue is that when I run classifier_spawner.py, after the subprocess has completed, the memory that it used is not freed and after ~10 classifications my disk is full (after writing ~15gb to disk). I then have to delete my virtual machine.

I don't understand why this is happening, shouldn't the virtual memory the subprocess uses be freed after (1) the TensorFlow session is ended and (2) the process has exited?

Thanks in advance, if you need any clarification please let me know.

Comment: I'm not familiar with tensorflow, but are you loading the model every time you launch a subprocess?

Comment: You can maybe try to add `tf.reset_default_graph()` at the end of `custom_classify_image.py` to release any ressource stored in the graph, but I am not sure it will help